# JBoss AS 5.1 JMS Queue NoInitialContextException

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I am trying to learn about JMS Queue in JBoss, however I have run into an error. I am following the tutorial on this page: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JMS_Examples-A_Point_To_Point_Example.html

I get an error on this line: `Object tmp = iniCtx.lookup("ConnectionFactory")`

Here's the full error:

```
Jul 7, 2016 3:10:23 PM com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient main
INFO: Begin SendRecvClient, now = 1467918623762
Jul 7, 2016 3:10:23 PM com.cloudet.jms.SendRecvClient sendRecvAsync
INFO: Begin sendRecvAsync
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient.setupPointToPoint(SendRecvClient.java:49)
    at com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient.sendRecvAsync(SendRecvClient.java:67)
    at com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient.main(SendRecvClient.java:106)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient.sendRecvAsync(SendRecvClient.java:71)
    at com.cloudlet.jms.SendRecvClient.main(SendRecvClient.java:106)
```

My code is exactly the same as the one in the link provided. I looked it up and found out I need some `jndi.properties` file inside the JBoss folder. Unfortunately, that file is not in the JBoss folder. I looked up some examples on what it would look like but every example was different.

How would I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by manually making a `Properties` object with the necessary key/value pairs then passing it to the `InitialContext` constructor.

**JBoss** properties:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
properties.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jnp://localhost:1099");
properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(properties);
```

I get the same output from the provided link in the opening post.